# Haskell: how to make a class with constructor?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a class which has a constructor. For example:

```
class A a where

  -- `a`'s field
  type T a

  -- default value
  defT :: T a

  -- constructor
  mk :: T a -> a
```

I also need a default constructor:

```
mkDef :: A a => a
mkDef = mk defT
```

But I get compilation error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘T a’ with actual type ‘T a1’
NB: ‘T’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘a1’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  mkDef :: a
In the first argument of ‘mk’, namely ‘defT’
In the expression: mk defT
```

I think compiler doesn't know which instance of `A a` the first argument of `mk` belongs to. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Attempt to use `ScopedTypeVariables` doesn't help here, I get mostly the same compilation error:

```
mkDef :: forall a . A a => a
mkDef = mk (defT :: T a)
```

Another idea would be to use `FunctionalDependencies`:

```
class A' a t | a -> t where

  -- Get t from a
  getT' :: a -> t

  defT' :: t

  mk' :: t -> a
```

But, still, I can't get working default constructor:

```
mkDef' :: forall a t . A' a t => a
mkDef' = make def
  where

    def :: t
    def = defT' `asTypeOf` (getT' (undefined :: a))

    make :: t -> a
    make = mk'
```

Information about which `a` `t` belongs is lost:

```
Could not deduce (A' a0 t) arising from a use of ‘defT'’
from the context (A' a t)
  bound by the type signature for mkDef' :: A' a t => a
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  def :: t
  make :: t -> a
In the first argument of ‘asTypeOf’, namely ‘defT'’
In the expression: defT' `asTypeOf` (getT' (undefined :: a))
In an equation for ‘def’:
    def = defT' `asTypeOf` (getT' (undefined :: a))
```

Also I don't like this approach because all such `t` should be a class parameters.

---

I'd like to solve it staying with `TypeFamilies` 'cause I already have some code written in such manner. Also, please let me know is there a common solution for this problem or not.

Comment: A `class` in Haskell is not a class like in Java. It is more an `interface` in Java. Hence you cannot attach a type to it. You can of course make a `null` (some sort of default constructor), with `null :: a` here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought about making something like `null :: a`. But it's not enough. I feel like I'm going in wrong direction :(

Comment: @wowofbob It's a bit tough to tell what you want, but I propose another direction you could consider that might get closer to your goal. I agree with Willem that you seem to be misunderstanding what classes are used for in Haskell.

Comment: Generally speaking, where you would make a class in OOP, in Haskell you would make a *module*, not a typeclass. The exports of the module correspond to the public interface of the class.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is lack of injectivity, as it usually happens with type families. Consider this.

```
data T1 = ...
data T2 = ...

instance A T1 where
  type T T1 = Int
  ...
instance A T2 where
  type T T2 = Int
  ...

mk defT :: T1  -- error
```

The last line requires `defT :: Int`. However, both instances define `defT :: Int ~ T T1 ~ T T2`, so GHC can't decide which one to pick.

Worse, GHC refuses the type `defT :: T a` in the type class, since it's ambiguous: even if we know that we want `defT :: SomeGivenType`, there is no way that GHC can understand what `a` it should choose.

The easiest solution, in my opinion, is to: 1) allow ambiguous types, and 2) to choose the instance explicitly.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}
mk (defT @ T1)  -- after the @ we explicitly pass the type "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want a new data type, not a class. For example:

```
data A a = Mk { get :: a }
```

This defines a bunch of stuff for you, but of especial interest are these two functions:

```
Mk :: a -> A a
get :: A a -> a
```

You can have multiple fields; for example, in:

```
data Counted a = Counted { value :: a, count :: Int }
```

These functions now exist:

```
Counted :: a -> Int -> Counted a
value :: Counted a -> a
count :: Counted a -> Int
```

Comment: I have a bunch of classes like `HashDBUser` from `Yesod.Auth.HashDB`. I need them to get rid of dependency from `Model.hs` in `yesod` scaffolding site. But in some cases I need to create records in database, so I need a constructors. I mean, I can't use `data`, or maybe I don't know how to do it properly. If I'll use `data`, I'll need a way, some proxy between this `data` and actual record type stored in database. As I see now, my question is a bit confusing :)

Comment: @wowofbob Sounds like you've scrubbed all the relevant details from your question, then. I suspect you did that to try to make your example as minimal as possible, which all of us here appreciate very much. But you've gone too far, I think; I encourage you to open a fresh question with just a few more of the background details explaining what you're trying to do and why.